# Split string with digit as marker

Tags: java

What is the most elegant way of returning the elements from a string untill a digit is recognized?

example:

```
test213home --> test
234tower --> 
test --> test
```

And the other question:

What is the most elegant way of returning the elements from a string after a digit is recognized?

example:

```
test213home --> 213home
234tower --> 234tower
test -->
```

Comment: Not seeing what makes this a Java question. Have you tried anything already?

Comment: Please define *"elegant"*. That's a very subjective word. "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder" one might say.

Comment: please share your code how you have tried to solve this so far.

Answer (score 4):

You should not code in "elegant way". Either you take a simple solution (in meaning easy to write/read/maintain (is not necessary in all cases the fastest possible) or a solution which fulfill your requirements (size, speed, whatever).

A possible simple solution (based on your examples) could be

```
String[] strings = { "test213home", "234tower", "test", "foo42bar23"};
for (String string : strings) {
    String first = string.replaceFirst("^([^\\d]*).*", "$1");
    String last = string.replaceFirst("^[^\\d]*(.*)", "$1");
    System.out.printf("value: %-11s   first: %-4s   last: %s%n", string, first, last);
}
```

output

```
value: test213home   first: test   last: 213home
value: 234tower      first:        last: 234tower
value: test          first: test   last: 
value: foo42bar23    first: foo    last: 42bar23
```

For the explanation of the regular expressions I would suggest you to read this [Java tutorial about "Regular Expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)

**edit** Find a snippet for your question in the comment.

```
String[] strings1 = { "12345test123", "test123abc"};
for (String string : strings1) {
    String first = string.replaceFirst("^([^\\d]*[\\d]*).*", "$1");
    String last = string.replaceFirst("^[^\\d]*[\\d]*(.*)", "$1");
    System.out.printf("value: %-12s   first: %-7s   last: %s%n", string, first, last);
}
```

output

```
value: 12345test123   first: 12345     last: test123
value: test123abc     first: test123   last: abc
```

Comment: thx you - what would be the regex for splitting after the last digit in a row inside a string?

like a) 12345test123 to --> 12345 and test123
or b) test123abc -->  test123 and abc

Comment: @DoeDoe Have a look in my updated answer to find a possible solution for your second question. For further questions have a look in the posted tutorial and post your own effort in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
String [] parts = str.split("\\d+")
```

Answer (score 0):

For first question this function is worked :

```
String  getSubstringUntilFirstNumber(String source) {
    return source.split("[0-9]")[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-regex approach where you search for the index of a digit, within the string, if there is one.  Then you just get the `substring` the result out.  Note the ternary selection if no digit is found.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = { "test213home", "234tower", "test", "foo42bar23" };
        for (String d : data) {
            System.out.println("Before digit: " + beforeDigit(d));
            System.out.println("After digit : " + afterDigit(d));
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    private static String beforeDigit(String data) {
        int index = findDigitIndex(data);
        return index > -1 
            ? data.substring(0, index)
            : data.substring(0);
    }

    private static String afterDigit(String data) {
        int index = findDigitIndex(data);
        return index > -1
            ? data.substring(index)
            : data.substring(0);
    }

    private static int findDigitIndex(String data) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i))) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Before digit: test
After digit : 213home

Before digit: 
After digit : 234tower

Before digit: test
After digit : test

Before digit: foo
After digit : 42bar23
```